# Algebraic singular moduli

Tags: number-theory, modular-function, modular-forms, elliptic-modular-form

I am trying to understand a point made by Zagier in the paper [*Elliptic Modular Forms and Their Applications*](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0_1/fulltext.pdf). Proposition 22 is the statement that if $\tau$ in the upper half plane $\mathcal{H}$ is a CM-point, then $j(\tau)$ is an algebraic number. Here $j(\tau)$ is the [$j$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant).

In the proof, he considers a matrix
$$M = \left(\matrix{B &C\\-A & 0}\right)$$
containing the coefficients for the quadratic relation $A\tau^2+B\tau+C = 0$ satisfied by $\tau$, where $A,B,C\in\mathbb{Z}$ (since $\tau$ is a CM point). As $\tau\in\mathcal{H}$ we know that $\det(M)>0$, although $M$ may not be in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. We consider the finite-index subgroup

$$H:=SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\cap M^{-1}SL_2(\mathbb{Z})M.$$

Zagier then says that since the functions $j(z)$ and $j(Mz)$ are modular functions for the subgroup $H$ they are algebraically dependent (as functions). Note that $\tau$ is fixed by the action of $M$ on $\mathcal{H}$ by definition of $M$.

I don't understand why this is the case. I do know that if $\Gamma\subseteq SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a finite-index subgroup then the dimension of the vector space $M_k(\Gamma)$ of modular forms of weight $k$ for $\Gamma$ is finite. In this case, we are considering modular functions i.e. modular forms of weight $k=0$ for the subgroup $H$. However, there are two important differences: firstly, we are not considering the linear structure but rather the multiplicative structure, of which I know nothing about. Secondly, $j(\tau)$ is not a modular form in the classical sense but rather a meromorphic modular form with a pole at infinity.

The only idea I have is that successive powers of $j(M\tau)$ generate copies of the functions 
$$j(A_1\tau), \dots, j(A_n\tau)$$
for a complete set of coset representatives of $H$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. However, I'm not really sure how to prove this.

Is there a way to understand why $j(z)$ and $j(M z)$ must be algebraically dependent in this case?

Comment: First, let me remark that for most authors a modular function is not the same thing as a modular form of degree 0. Modular forms are required to be holomorphic at infinity, whereas modular functions are just meromorphic.

Comment: @DocteurCottard oops, good point! I will edit the question to point out that $j(z)$ is not a modular form in the usual sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a geometric picture which is useful to have in mind.

The quotient of the Poincaré upper half-plane by the group $H$ is a Riemann surface, which you can compactify to obtain a compact Riemann surface $X$ (which is a fortiori an algebraic curve). Modular functions for $H$ may be identified with meromorphic functions on $X$. As $X$ is of dimension one, its function field $\mathbf{C}(X)$ has transcendence degree 1 over $\mathbf{C}$, so any two meromorphic functions on $X$ are algebraically dependent.

Comment: $X$ of dimension $1$ ? You meant genus $0$, which can be shown from how the edges of the fundamental domain are identified (making it homeomorphic to the Riemann sphere) or from the fact $j(\tau)$ has a unique simple pole

Comment: I mean that $X$ is a curve.

Comment: Ok, but the OP will need that it is of genus $0$ to show $j(\tau)$ is algebraic whenever $\tau \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$

Comment: @reuns why do you need to know the genus is $0$? Surely the fact that the function field has tr-degree $1$ over $\mathbb{C}$ suffices?

Comment: @reuns also it is not immediately clear how you can show the genus is $0$ from the definition of $H$. Doesn't this depend on $M$ in some way?

Comment: @AlexSaad Please, correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think it is true that $X$ is of genus 0 for any $M$. If you take $A=1$, $B=0$ and $C=N$, then $H$ is conjugate in $SL_2(\mathbf{Z})$ to $\Gamma_0(N)$, so the genus of $X$ is the genus of $X_0(N)$.

Comment: Sure the genus of $\mathcal{H}/\Gamma_0(N)$ is arbitrary large. @AlexSaad In [Zagier](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0_1/fulltext.pdf) p.69 it is using that the function field of $\mathcal{H}/SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is $\mathbb{C}(j(z))$ to find that $\Psi_n(x) = \prod_{d | n, b < d} (j(\frac{\frac{n}{d}z+b}{d})-x)= \sum_{k=0}^m c_k(z) x^k$ has coefficients being modular for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and hence in $\mathbb{C}(j(z))$ and even $\mathbb{Q}(j(z))$ and $\mathbb{Z}[j(z)]$ by looking at the $q$-expansions.

Comment: Then we use that for $\tau \in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ then $\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}$ has CM by an order of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ to find $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^{2 \times 2}, \det(\alpha) = n$ such that $j(\alpha \tau) = j(\tau)$. Since $\det(\alpha)= n$ then $j(\alpha \tau)$ is a root of $\Psi_n(x)$, obtaining $\Psi_n(j(\alpha \tau)) = \Psi_n(j(\tau)) = 0$, and when $n$ is not a square the $q$-expansion shows $\Psi_n(j(z))$ is a non-identically zero polynomial in $j(z)$.

Comment: Of course - I didn't mean to suggest $X$ always has genus 0. I only mentioned this as I thought @reuns was saying it is always genus 0 and I didn't understand why. Apologies for the confusion.